# Parallel chapters in eledpar

Tags: sectioning, chapters, eledmac

I'm trying to typeset two parallel texts using `eledpar`. I want to have `\chapter` in both texts independently running in parallel. I would want to have two independent TOCs. When I add them they are typeset one after another not in parallel. How can I make parallel `\chapter`s in `eledpar`?

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[xetex,a4paper,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{bidi}
\usepackage{eledmac}
\usepackage{eledpar}    
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}    
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\russianfont[Script=Cyrillic]{Linux Libertine O}    
\newcommand{\mybeginru}{ %
\begin{russian}%
\begin{Leftside} %
\beginnumbering%
}
\newcommand{\mybeginhe}{ %
\begin{RTL}%
\begin{hebrew}%
\begin{Rightside} %
\beginnumbering%
}
\newcommand{\myendru}{ %
\endnumbering%
\end{Leftside}%
\end{russian}%
\Columns
}
\newcommand{\myendhe}{ %
\endnumbering%
\end{Rightside}%
\end{hebrew}%
\end{RTL}%
} 

\begin{document}
\numberlinefalse
\numberpstarttrue 
\sidepstartnumtrue 

\begin{pairs}
\mybeginhe
\chapter{המאמר השני}
\pstart
בפנות התוריות, ר״ל שהם יסודות ועמודים אשר בית אלהים נכון עליהם, ובמציאותם יציר מציאות התורה מסדרת ממנו יתברך, ואלו יציר העדר אחת מהם תפל התורה בכללה חלילה.
\pend    
\myendhe
\mybeginru
\chapter{Трактат Второй}    
\pstart
О краеугольных [принципах] Торы, имеется ввиду, которые [есть] основы и столпы на которых дом Б-жий опирается/нахон, и с существованием их может быть представлено существование Торы упорядоченной от Него, благословенного, и если бы было представлено отсутствие одного из них — упадет Тора в общем, [Б-же] упаси.
\pend
\myendru
\end{pairs}
\end{document}
```

Here's what I have:

[image]

Here's what I want:

[image]

Comment: I am afraid it is not possible un two columns mode. Try with eledchapter. Otherwise, open an issue on gihtub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the 1.12.0 /1.8.0 version of eledmac/eledpar should help you.

There is new commands, call \eledchapter, which work right in parallel columns.

That is a MWE

```
\beforeeledchapter
\begin{pairs}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering

\pstart
\eledchapter{\edtext{xxx}{\Afootnote{yyyy}}}
\pend
\pstart
DI use s git to manage some package.
I would like to add a pre-commit hook, to check if I have forgotten
For now, I have a minimal pre-commit, which test only the blank spaces at ends of lines, but not the forgotten..
\pend
\pstart
\eledsection{xxxx}
\pend
\pstart
\eledsubsection{xxxx}
\pend
\pstart
\eledsubsubsection{sssxxxx}
\pend
\pstart
\edtext{D}{\Afootnote{C}}I use s git to manage some package.
I would like to add a pre-commit hook, to check if I have forgotten
For now, I have a minimal pre-commit, which test only the blank spaces at ends of lines, but not the forgotten.\edtext{E}{\Afootnote{F}}.
\pend
\pstart
\eledsection{\edtext{xxx}{\Afootnote{yyyy}}}
\pend
\pstart
\edtext{D}{\Afootnote{C}}I use s git to manage some package.
I would like to add a pre-commit hook, to check if I have forgotten
For now, I have a minimal pre-commit, which test only the blank spaces at ends of lines, but not the forgotten.\edtext{E}{\Afootnote{F}}.
\pend


\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering

\pstart
\eledchapter{\edtext{xxx}{\Afootnote{yyyy}}}
\pend
\pstart
DI use s git to manage some package.
I would like to add a pre-commit hook, to check if I have forgotten
For now, I have a minimal pre-commit, which test only the blank spaces at ends of lines, but not the forgotten..
\pend
\pstart
\eledsection{xxxx}
\pend
\pstart
\eledsubsection{xxxx}
\pend
\pstart
\eledsubsubsection{sssxxxx}
\pend
\pstart
\edtext{D}{\Afootnote{C}}I use s git to manage some package.
I would like to add a pre-commit hook, to check if I have forgotten
For now, I have a minimal pre-commit, which test only the blank spaces at ends of lines, but not the forgotten.\edtext{E}{\Afootnote{F}}.
\pend
\pstart
\eledsection{\edtext{xxx}{\Afootnote{yyyy}}}
\pend
\pstart
\edtext{D}{\Afootnote{C}}I use s git to manage some package.
I would like to add a pre-commit hook, to check if I have forgotten
For now, I have a minimal pre-commit, which test only the blank spaces at ends of lines, but not the forgotten.\edtext{E}{\Afootnote{F}}.
\pend


\endnumbering

\end{Rightside}
\Columns
\end{pairs}
```

This version will be released soon. Could you try for me?
- dowload https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/archive/issue165.zip
- run the .ins file to obtain .sty file
- try with your file, following the MWE (which is present in the zip)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Maïeul, much appreciated. There are some issues. 
Chapter titles are misaligned vertically. 
Hebrew\RTL support is broken. 
\eledchapter being between \pstart and \pend is numbered with the paragraphs.
That being said, it's a huge improvement.

[Missalignment example](http://s29.postimg.org/6mcinjm2v/165.png)

[Proper Hebrew\RTL example](http://s12.postimg.org/jqwk4u4a5/165heb_chapter.png)

Comment: hum, please open a issue with your MWE code...

Comment: and so? the MWE to debug this problem with Hebrew?

Comment: Submitted at github. [https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues](https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues)

Comment: I have answer in the tickets. Please tests them, to allow me to quickly publish this release.

Comment: so, the version 1.12.2 will be publish soon (1.12.0 and 1.12.1 are buged)

Comment: published now...